# How to properly disable Wordpress sign out confirmation for users?

Tags: php, wordpress, logout, confirmation

I'm building a marketplace on Wordpress and trying to figure out how to disable  Wordpress default logout confirmation screen after the user click on sign out.

The code I'm using to sign out is `<a title="Sign out" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('/') ?>">Sign out</a>`

I tried almost every code I found on Google to add to my functions.php but none of them works. The confirmation page is still coming but the weird thing is it doesn't appear every time i try to sign out, it appears sometimes.

How can we solve this issue? There's no way to completely disable it?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-to-log-out-without-confirmation-do-you-really-want-to-log-out/248743 might be of use.

Comment: I'm using the same code but it doesn't work. It still asks for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a marketplace too but not on wordpress it is on core php   where are you from?

We might help each other

Answer (score 0):

You just add logout link without back-url like this:

```
 <a title="Sign out" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url() ?>">Sign out</a>
```

It will logout you immediately, there is no confirmation page here.

Its work for me.